# Elmah and code obfuscation

Tags: .net, obfuscation, elmah

This is most probably a stupid question, but I'd like to make sure I did not miss anything:

Am I right to assume that using [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) and code obfuscation at the same time does not make much sense since Elmah won't be able to produce any meaningful call stacks?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly. Some obfuscators provide somethink like mapping table, so from obfuscated call stack, the developer can get meaningfull data. For example, [dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions) calls it "Stack Trace Translation".

Comment: But for that to work wouldn't I would have debug the binary and use the pdb file and / or the mapping file created by the obfuscator? One of the great things about Elmah is that I can browse crashes and view call stacks directly without even starting my IDE.

Comment: The obfuscated assembly contains obfuscated names (functions,fileds...). So any crash dump, call stack log... contains obfuscated names. You would have to use the mapping functionality provided by the obfuscator engine. This is why to obfuscate. Obfuscated assembly does not know anythink about the real (developer frendly) names.